# I need to make a plugin that will take effect the user chooses

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am developing a jquery plugin and the problem I have is that when trying to pass settings, works with two of the three options I try to set. When I want to pass the "fadeIn" effect does not display me anything and stops working. This is my code:

```js
// JavaScript Document
jQuery.fn.slider = function(opciones) {

  var configuracion = {
    efecto: "fadeIn",
    velocidadEfecto: 1000,
    tiempoPausa: 3000
  }

  jQuery.extend(configuracion, opciones);

  this.each(function() {
    elem = $(this);
    elem.find('div:gt(0)').hide();

    //$('#imagenes div:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function() {
      elem.find('div:first-child').fadeOut(0)
        .next('div')[configuracion.efecto](configuracion.velocidadEfecto)
        .end().appendTo('#imagenes');
    }, configuracion.tiempoPausa);

  });




  return this;
};
```

```css
#imagenes {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Documento sin título</title>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#imagenes").slider({
        efecto: "slideUp",
        velocidadEfecto: 2000,
        tiempoPausa: 4000
      })
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <h2>Slider</h2>
  <div id="imagenes">
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.bizreport.com/2011/02/03/android-logo-200x200.jpg" id="foto1" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://davidnaylor.org/temp/firefox-logo-200x200.png" id="foto2" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://tech21info.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/chrome-logo-200x200.png" id="foto3" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I don't understand why "**slideUp**" effect not working. Thank you!

Regards! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference methods and attributes via string names, like "fadeIn" in your example, but you have to use bracket `[]` notation, not dot `.`

```
setInterval(function() {
  elem.find('div:first-child').fadeOut(0)
    .next('div')[configuracion.efecto](configuracion.velocidadEfecto)
    .end().appendTo('#imagenes');
}, configuracion.tiempoPausa);
```

If you don't use brackets, Javascript is going to look for a `configuracion` property on the `next('div')` object, with an `efecto` method attached to it (which isn't the case). Using brackets works out to `.next('div')['fadeIn'](configuracion.velocidadEfecto)` because `configuracion.efecto` is evaluated to its string value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank for your answer Rob! I understand and i change my code, but when i pass a "slideUp" effect also stop work.

Comment: No problem @Emily, you are having this problem because `slideUp` is way to _hide_ elements, not show them (http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) - try `slideToggle` instead

Comment: you're amazing!! Thank you for your help and your time! Now I understand! Sorry for the inconvenience! Regards! ;-)